# How is mod mysteriously useful in this DP problem, and what is the underlying algorithm?

Tags: c, algorithm, dynamic-programming, trace

The DP question is as follows: Given a list of non-negative numbers and a target integer k, write a function to check if the array has a continuous subarray of size at least 2 that sums up to a multiple of k, that is, sums up to n*k where n is also an integer.

Example 1:

Input: [23, 2, 4, 6, 7],  k=6
Output: True
Explanation: Because [2, 4] is a continuous subarray of size 2 and sums up to 6.

Example 2:

Input: [23, 2, 6, 4, 7],  k=6
Output: True
Explanation: Because [23, 2, 6, 4, 7] is an continuous subarray of size 5 and sums up to 42.

I've spent quite some time understanding the following solution to this problem:

```c
typedef struct e_s {
    int mod;
    int idx;
    struct e_s *shadow;
} e_t;
#define SZ 1024
e_t *lookup(e_t **set, int mod) {
    e_t *e = set[mod % SZ];
    while (e && e->mod != mod) {
        e = e->shadow;
    }
    return e;
}
void put(e_t **set, e_t *e, int mod, int idx) {
    e->mod = mod;
    e->idx = idx;
    e->shadow = set[mod % SZ];
    set[mod % SZ] = e;
}
bool checkSubarraySum(int* nums, int numsSize, int k) {
    int i, s, found = 0;

    e_t buff[10000];
    int n;

    e_t *set[SZ] = { 0 }, *e;

    put(set, &buff[n ++], 0, -1);

    s = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < numsSize; i ++) {
        s += nums[i];
        if (k) s = s % k;
        e = lookup(set, s);
        if (e) {
            if (i - e->idx >= 2) {
                found = 1;
                break;
            }
        } else {
            put(set, &buff[n ++], s, i);
        }
    }

    return found;
}
```

I even traced an example here which took quite a while, but I can't think of why mod values are important in this question, or even if I traced correctly.

```
Example:
Input = 23, 2, 6, 4, 7
k = 6

buff = [e_t, e_t, ...] (size = 10000)
SZ = 1024
set = [NULL, NULL, ...] (size = 1024)

put(set, &buff[0], 0, -1);
Now n = 1

buff = [(0, -1, NULL), e_t, e_t...]
set = [(0, -1, NULL), NULL, NULL...]

i = 0
s = 0
s = 23
s = 5
e = NULL
put(set, &buff[1], 5, 0);
Now n = 2

buff = [(0, -1, NULL), (5, 0, NULL), e_t...]
set = [(0, -1, NULL), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, (5, 0, NULL), ...]

i = 1
s = 7
s = 1
e = NULL
put(set, &buff[2], 1, 1);
Now n = 3

buff = [(0, -1, NULL), (5, 0, NULL), (1, 1, NULL), e_t...]
set = [(0, -1, NULL), (1, 1, NULL), NULL, NULL, NULL, (5, 0, NULL), ...]

i = 2
s = 7
s = 1
e = (1, 1, NULL)

i = 3
s = 5
e = (5, 0, NULL)

Since i = 3, and e->idx = 0, (i - e->idx >= 2) evaluates to True. The function returns true. Why though...?
```

At the end of the day, my question comes down to what kind of algorithm is being used here? What's up with the linked lists? And did I trace this correctly?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the original statement please ?

Comment: One reason to use the `%` mod operator on an array index is to keep the index within bounds. For example when encrypting a message, and you have `char key[5]` then for the character at index `i` in the message you use the key element at `key[index % 5]`.

Comment: @herophant A link to the web page where you found this question and the example solution.

Comment: @fjardon The original restrictions are as such: The length of the array won't exceed 10,000. You may assume the sum of all the numbers is in the range of a signed 32-bit integer.

Nothing about 1024 is mentioned. Seems that the author picked this at random.

Comment: Here is the original statement: https://leetcode.com/problems/continuous-subarray-sum/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The algorithm runs through the array starting at index 0. It maintains a sum modulo `k` of the array elements seen so far. This sum is `s`. Once `s` is updated for the current element, the value `s` is looked up in a hash-table, in order to get the index at which the sum `A[0]+...+A[i] % k` is equal to `s`. If this index is found and the distance to the current position is greater or equal to 2, the algorithm returns. If there was no index the current index is stored in the hash-table for the value `s`. The idea is that if `(A[0]+...+A[i] % k) = (A[0]+...+A[i]+...+A[j] %k)` then `A[i+1]+...+A[j] % k = 0`.

There are two modulos in the code, one is modulo `k` and derives from the fact that a multiple of `k` is equal to `0 % k`. The second modulo is a modulo `SZ` and is used to address the [hash-table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) (which is called a `set` here). This hash-table uses linked-list (using the `shadow` field) to resolve conflicts.

The memory for the hash-table nodes is statically allocated in the `buff` array.

The value of `SZ` was arbitrary chosen by the author to ensure an average conflict rate.

Given the maximal value of `k` we could completely get rid of the hash-table and nodes and just use an array of size 10000 to store the index of each `mod`.

Comment: For this hash table, what is lookup doing? Specifically: `while (e && e->mod != mod) {`? We're looking for something with the same mod as the one passed in, but as long as `k`is less than SZ, the mod will always be mod, i.e. almost always `mod == mod % SZ`. Is this interpretation correct? Does this mean that for smaller `k` such as 6, this isn't really necessary? Do we need to check `e->mod != mod` at all when going through the linked list?

Comment: I don't see how the following is true: "The memory for the hash-table is statically allocated in the `buff` array." To me `buff` and `set` seem two separate entities...

Comment: The original statement would give us the exact upper-limits for each parameter of the problem. From the code we can deduce that the author though that most `k` would be greater than 1024. Indeed, from the size of `buff` we can deduce that the author though `k` maximal value is `10000`. In that case, we absolutely need to check `e->mod != mod` because different `mod` values can conflict modulo `SZ`.

Comment: The hash-table array is `set`, it contains pointers to `e_t` elements which are the nodes of the hash-table. These nodes are statically allocated in `buff`.

Comment: The reason that I was saying that `e->mod != mod` is unnecessary is because `lookup`, before that line, does this: `e_t *e = set[mod % SZ];`. So that would automatically mean that all the elements in the linked list in that array item will actually have `e->mod == mod`. So in the end, we just end up picking the first element in the linked list. What I'm trying to understand is, if we just pick the first element in the linked list, why bother with the while loop at all?

Comment: No, `2049 % SZ == 1 % SZ`. `mod` can take any value in `[0, k-1]` and `k` may be greater than `SZ`.